# Adding text to a CSV file through shell script

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I can use the below command to write text to beginning of each line in the file

```
sed 's/^/Adding Text /' filename
```

But I want to skip the first line and add a another text to the first line alone at the beginning.

My current file:

```
Summary, Task Id, Project ID, Project
Test file for Project Task, T12345, P123456, Test
```

The Output I am looking for is:

```
Type, Summary, Task Id, Project ID, Project
Adding Text, Test1 file for Project Task, T12345, P123456, Test
Adding Text, Test1 file for Project Task, T12345, P123456, Test
```

`Type` should be added to the first line and `Adding Text` should be added to all other lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
sed '1s/^/Type, /;2,$s/^/Adding Text, /' filename
```

`1s/^Type, /` : insert `Type,` at the beginning of 1st line
`2,$s/^/Adding Text, /` : starting from 2nd line, insert `Adding Text,` at the beginning of each line

or you can use `awk`

```
awk 'NR==1{print "Type,",$0}NR>1{print "Adding Text,",$0}' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one `awk`

```
awk '{print NR==1?"Type,":"Adding Text,",$0}' file
```

### It test if line is number `1` and print one thing, if not print some other.

It may be some more robust using parentheses.

```
awk '{print (NR==1?"Type,":"Adding Text,"),$0}'
awk '{print (NR>1?"Adding Text,":"Type,"),$0}'
```